# Is it possible to hijack the javascript confirm function?

Tags: javascript, confirm, monkeypatching

I'm working on the front-end part of a project.

And the specified UI contains a set of dialogs which have same appearance on it.

Functionally speaking, two main of the dialogs behaves just like a *MessageBox* and *ConfirmBox*, the same with `window.alert` and `window.confirm`.

So, I'm trying to hijack the two functions, that when I call `window.alert(msg)`, it shows my custom dialog:

```
<div id="dialog_alert">
    <p class="dialog_content">Message</p>
    <a class="btn-confirm">OK</a>
</div>
```

This behaves enough similar to the native `window.alert`.

---

#### Now comes the problem.

When I'm trying to hijack the `window.confirm`, I found it seems not possible:

```
window.confirm = function(message) {
    var $dialog = $('#dialog_confirm');
    $dialog.find('.dialog_content').text(message);
    $dialog.show();
    $dialog.find('.btn-yes').click(function() {
        return true;
    });
    $dialog.find('.btn-no').click(function() {
        return false;
    });
    // My GOD, I must return true or false immediately here.
};
```

As above, when I try to return the confirm result, because of the *single thread*/*event loop*/*callback* property of javascript, I just cannot work it out.

---

So, is it possible to hijack the confirm function as it was? I'm curious about an opinion, please help.

Comment: It's not possible. You can't create real modal "window"s using JS.

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript Confirm replacement with return true/false](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7016658/javascript-confirm-replacement-with-return-true-false)

Comment: I don't see any way of doing this, but rewriting the code isn't *that* much trouble...

Comment: I also don't quite understand why you want to *override* the alert/confirm functions, IMHO it's a lot better to add a new `window.better_alert` (or whatever) function, and do a project-wide search/replace ... I would only override built-in stuff if there's a good reason (...which I don't see here...)

Comment: Thank you all, I'm knowing about all you just told, and just been trying to find if there is some dark magic or so to achieve this. Thank you any way!

Comment: If the reason is just rewrite the global appearance of my project, and many `alert()` and `confirm()` calls were made, I don't want to change those code. Isn't it a good reason?

Comment: In my opinion, it's not :-) Searching for these function calls is very simple, as is replacing them (certainly a lot easier than what this question is trying to ask); for example, something like this may be enough: `find . -name '*.js' -exec sed -i.orig 's/ alert\(/ alert(/g' {} \;` ... Many IDE's have features for this as well... For `confirm` calls it's a bit more work, but not that much...